# System.Drawing.Bitmap error

Tags: vb.net, image, bitmap, drawing, windows-ce

I have a project with several forms that contain a picturebox (which sometimes contains an image). When I debug my project, I get an error message that says: "System.Drawing.Bitmap". After placing breakpoints in my code, I removed the picturebox from the form. When I go to the next form that contains a picturebox, I get the same error again...

I can't keep deleting all the pictureboxes. I need a solution. Problem is I can't really find any similar problems. I guess there is something wrong with some kind of references of the images or they are not being found...

My project is made for mobile devices / PDA's or `Windows CE` and written in `VB.net`.

Comment: i think there is more to the error message than just that; added CE tag

Comment: Is this an error at runtime on the device, or in the designer?

Comment: No there isn't much more to the error.. only nullexception and it happens on runtime

Comment: I think it has something to do with not finding the images.. what I don't understand cause the images are project.. i'm figuring it out..

Comment: Please post the full exception text and any inner exceptions as well, plus the stack trace.  Can you show the line of code where the exception is raised?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same picture in multiple places? Are the images being disposed or cloned correctly?

If you use the same image multiple times, try calling `.Clone` (but don't forget to call `.Dispose` when you are done with the clone)

How are the images being loaded / stored?